# Make VSCode apply syntax highlighting to .tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsx

Trying to start a gatsby+react+typescript project and VSCode will only apply syntax highlighting to the HTML in my .tsx files. The typescript code remains a single color. How do I fix this?

Note: I have no plugins installed at the moment and the highlighting works if the file type is set to .jsx

[image: related image]

Comment: https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages/typescript/

Comment: What language mode is shown in the lower right corner of the status bar? The file icon suggest that it's not set to `typescript`

Comment: looks like it thinks the file is XML.

Comment: Does it work properly if you set it to `typescript react`? Have you configured `files.associations` so that `tsx` files would be treated as `xml`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clicking on the language button in the lower right corner and selecting typescript react fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue just reloading vscode as required by `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extension, once it was reload I just double checked that **Typescript react** was selected and the problem was resolved.

Seems like the real problem was that the library `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` was not fully reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, even "Typescript React" was selected as the language. I had to click and select the language pack  version before getting syntax highlighting working.

[image: vscode select language pack version]

Answer (score 0):

***In my case "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" extension was causing the problem.***
I had the same problem even when "Typescript React" was selected.
I disabled all the extensions and problem solved.
Then I enabled each extension individually and I've found out "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" was causing the problem.
I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension solved it (Settings on Auto-Detect)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got mine to work:

1. Click settings for the installed extension
2. Click 'Extension Settings' from the drop down should see '@ext:kamikillerto.vscode-colorize' in the search bar up top.
3. Select the option Colorize: Include -> 'Edit in settings.json
   [image]
4. add `"**/*.tsx"` to the `colorize.include` array.
   [image]